# Increment text files names - windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

I have a directory full with textfiles, all named illogically. I would like to change all these textfiles their name to numbers which just increment (i.e. 1.txt , 2.txt, 3.txt ...). I do not care in which order, just that their names are changed. I'm working on windows, so a windows appropriate answer is appreciated.

Comment: Select them all and rename.

Comment: @sergmat, I couldn't believe that would work so I had to try it, I'm amazed.  Knowing that would have saved me SO much time

Comment: @sergmat , I selected them all, then left the name blank, hit enter. I have a list which looks like this : (1).txt, (2).txt ... . I don't want the brackets. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Ojtwist It`s by design.

Comment: Your method worked btw (just added the () in my code). If you put your answer as an ... answer, I'' accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous numbering of files with bat-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583695/continuous-numbering-of-files-with-bat-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need batch file. Shell amazing does it. Select all files in a folder and click rename.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: `If you put your answer as an ... answer, I'' accept it` – Ojtwist

Answer (score 1):

this code changes all the files in the directory in to 1.txt 2.txt so on

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "\currentdirectory where files are present"
set /a incr=0
FOR %%G in ("*.txt") DO call :rename "%%G"


:rename
set file1=%~1 
set /a incr=!incr!+1
ren !file1! !incr!.txt
endlocal
```